# How can I iterate this loop 3 times then brake out of it then saving the contents into a wav file in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code spawns random objects in unity and i want to know how to brake out of it and create a wav file and output it because the project I am working a melody generator with premade objects that produce sound and I was wondering how could I make it so it doesn't infinitely loop and when it ends to create a wav file so i could play it back on demand.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class RandomizedSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab1, prefab2, prefab3, prefab4, prefab5;

    public float spawnRate = 2f;

    float nextspawn = 0f;

    int WhatToSpawn;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time > nextspawn)
        {
            WhatToSpawn = Random.Range(1, 5);
            Debug.Log(WhatToSpawn);

            switch (WhatToSpawn)
            {
                case 1:
                    Instantiate(prefab1, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Instantiate(prefab2, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Instantiate(prefab3, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Instantiate(prefab4, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Instantiate(prefab5, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
            }
            nextspawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: just use an int to count how much time you go through the loop (if you mean the Update method) ?

Comment: but i want this code to do something after the iterations and i don't know how to write it.

Comment: Put a counter and then `if(counter > 3){ do something } ` .  Also, this doesn't look like a loop to me but a function. Are you calling this function inside a loop?

Comment: Cylegend, Update is a Unity function that is being called every frame (still not really a loop)

Comment: I am not sure I saw this code in a youtube tutorial and i am trying to repurpose it into something i need it to do or is there a easier way of doing this in unity

Comment: alper mimoglu, please start using punctuation in your sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want, just refractored your code and added what you want :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class RandomizedSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject prefab1;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject prefab2;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject prefab3;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject prefab4;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject prefab5;
    [SerializeField] private float spawnRate = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private int maxSpawnCount = 3;

    private float _timer;

    private int _random;

    private int _spawnCount;

    private void Update()
    {

        if (_spawnCount < maxSpawnCount)
        {
            _timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (_timer >= spawnRate)
            {
                _timer -= spawnRate;
                SpawnRandomPrefab();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            YourOtherFunction();
        }

    }


    private void SpawnRandomPrefab()
    {
        // The second parameter is exclusive, so if you want to be able to get X, it needs to be X+1
        _random = Random.Range(1, 6);
        Debug.Log(_random);

        switch (_random)
        {
            case 1:
                Instantiate(prefab1, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
            case 2:
                Instantiate(prefab2, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
            case 3:
                Instantiate(prefab3, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
            case 4:
                Instantiate(prefab4, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
            case 5:
                Instantiate(prefab5, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
        }

        _spawnCount++;
    }

    private void YourOtherFunction()
    {

    }
}
```